# 'nvcc -ptx file.cu' fatal error: file not found

Tags: nvcc, ptx

I'm trying to build .ptx code using nvcc on the .cu files.  For some it works and for some it produces a "file not found" error:

```
macair93278:matrixMul r8t$ nvcc -ptx matrixMul.cu
matrixMul.cu:36:10: fatal error: 'helper_functions.h' file not found
#include <helper_functions.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

but then when I try another file it works:

```
macair93278:matrixMulCUBLAS r8t$ cd ../matrixMulDrv/
macair93278:matrixMulDrv r8t$ ls
Makefile        NsightEclipse.xml   matrixMulDrv.cpp    readme.txt
Makefile-e      matrixMul.h     matrixMul_kernel.cu
macair93278:matrixMulDrv r8t$ nvcc -ptx matrixMul_kernel.cu
macair93278:matrixMulDrv r8t$ ls
Makefile        NsightEclipse.xml   matrixMulDrv.cpp    matrixMul_kernel.ptx
Makefile-e      matrixMul.h     matrixMul_kernel.cu readme.txt
```

Maybe when I ran

```
make
```

on some of them my PATH variables were set differently? Any idea how to fix the ones that don't work?
Thanks, 
bb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give `nvcc` the path to any include files needed.  You do this in the same fashion that you would for `gcc`/`g++`.  The only include files that you don't have to specify this for (with `nvcc`) are the default ones located in `/usr/local/cuda/include`

So if, on your machine, `helper_functions.h` is located in `/usr/local/cuda/samples/common/inc`, then compile like this:

```
nvcc -ptx -I/usr/local/cuda/samples/common/inc matrixMul.cu
```

The reason it works for `matrixMul_kernel.cu` is because that file does not have the

```
#include <helper_functions.h>
```

statement in it.